# How can I send message to person via teams share button?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I created a Share to Teams embedded button refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams).
I can send message to team or channel but can't send to person although it says "This will allow you to share a link directly to any person or Microsoft Teams channel ".
How can I send message to person?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to better frame your question.